# Has flag system changed?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

I had 35 ok flags, but last three were declined. Two of them were deleted by users themselves, third is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35939522/get-value-from-seletected-dropdown-with-same-class-class-name/35939634#35939634), which is a copy-paste from somewhere (ts code is about cars: `filter("[value=audi]")`).

If the answer is not helpful in any way, has nothing to do with question, than I flag it as `not an answer`, but from Moderator I get:

> declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical
>   inaccuracies, or **an altogether wrong answer**

At the end, are there some new rules for flagging, or the system has changed? This looks like someone wants to discourage the Flag system to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not a new rule, flagging has never been appropriate for wrong answers.

The not an answer flag is appropriate for answers that ask additional questions e.g. *I have this problem too can you help me?*. Or things like *thanks a lot*. Neither of these can be answers to any question.

Moderators cannot be subject matter experts in all tags and cannot therefore be expected to judge whether an answer is right or wrong.

The answer you linked in the question does seem to be a genuine attempt to answer some question. If you think it is wrong or doesn't address the specifics of the question as asked, downvote it.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Still I can't downvote answers that stand besides my answer, it would make me feel bad.

Comment: Why should whether you answered the question or not make you want to waste other people's time trying bad answers that won't fix their problem? If you think about posts rather than users you won't go far wrong.

Comment: Well, that's chicken and the egg issue now. While moderator is maybe not an expert in the field, I consider me as one. Now I flag to delete the answer, but he says the answer is fine and I should downvote it instead. Which means on the other side that users won't waste their time reading it, at least not the way I did and spent half an hour. Other two flags I posted were 100% correct, still those were declined. I shall simply stop flagging the answers, because I do not approve this logic at all.